# SignalR .net Core Azure android implementation disconnection problem

Tags: android, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

In my android project chat application, I am using SignalR android library that is Signalr .net Core. I implemented the library as mentioned in documentation in below link of Microsoft official Asp.net core site
[Official Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

It is working fine and I am able to send and receive events. But the problem is SignalR gets disconnected automatically after some time. What I observer is it gets disconnected when I am not performing any activity(this means I am connected with SignalR and Idle means not calling any hub methods). Every 20 mnts it disconnects my user from hub. Why is that so? Is it happening because of I am using basic plan of Azure? I have gone through the document and could not see any thing like this if I have basic plan of azure then it allows me connectivity of 20 mnts only. I observed disconnectivity 6-8 times all of them hapened in exact 20 mnts. For reference I am attaching screen shot of azure portal where all connectivity graph is generated.
[image]
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a huge amount of time, atlast, I and one of my team member are able to solve this problem. Now posting the solution in future it may help others and save some times. It was not signal problem. The problem was with IIS server. It has default time of 20 minutes to clear things up. If IIS server does not receive any call in 20 mnts (that means IDLE) it clears up things so that cleans my signal hub as well. This was the problem behind disconnectivity. For the time being I am calling a web api method every 15 mnts to keep my IIS server alive/active. Although I know this is not the best solution but something is better nothing.